# fields_for has_many not showing as array on form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many, fields-for

Typically when I use a `fields_for` on a simple `has_many` association, the input names on the form look something like `foo[bars_attributes][0][name]`, but in my case, it's not showing up as an array on the form - instead I get something like `foo[bars][name]`, which will blow up when I try to submit because it's trying to assign to a name property of an array - and I can't figure out what's different from other cases. Here's the code, which has obviously been simplified and renamed for this venue.

My model:

```
  class Foo
    has_many :bars
  end
```

The controller:

```
  class FooController < ApplicationController
    def new
      @foo = Foo.new
      @foo.bars.build
      @foo
    end
  end
```

The view:

```
<div>
  <%= form_for @foo do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :bars do |bar_fields| %>
      <%= bar_fields.text_field :name %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="single_column">
      <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The resulting markup:

```
<input name="foo[bars][name]" id="foo_bars_name" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps `Foo` could merit with having `accepts_nested_attributes_for :bars` in it?

Comment: I always thought `accepts_nested_attributes_for` was something you needed at submission time. I was not expecting it to change how the names appeared on the rendered form elements, but it did. Thanks for throwing me the bone that I obviously should have had in place before posting this!